# How can I make the text go to the same height as some other text?

Tags: html, css

I have some text and want it to be higher and inline with the first icon. This is it live: http://www.penguinie.co.uk/#projects the css is:

```
.german img {
    height: 100;
    width: 100;
    padding: 2px 2px 1px 2px;
}

.german img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #2e8ece;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.german-content {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}

.german:hover .german-content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.german-content p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 30px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    color: black;
}

.chembond img {
    height: 100;
    width: 100;
    padding: 2px 2px 1px 2px;
}

.chembond img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #2e8ece;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.chembond-content {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
}

.chembond:hover .chembond-content {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.chembond-content p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 30px;
    word-spacing: 5px;
    color: black;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
        <section id="projects-content">
            <p>Projects</p>
            <section class="german">
                <img src="assets/img/german.png" height="60" width="50" />
                <section class="german-content">
                    <p>I started this project because I have seen many students in my German class keep on getting the tenses wrong by putting verbs in the wrong places, missunderstanding past participles etc... so I started this to help students (or anyone) understand the sometimes confusing German tenses. Each tense page consistes of three sub-sections: a question, an answer and a statement. These then in turn include an example and an explanation. If you were to hover over some of the words then a popup box will appear, explaining the use of the word. You can see it <a href="projects/german/">here</a> (please bare in mind that this is still a work in progress). If you want to email me a tip about it, or just ask me about it then don't hesitate to contact me.</p>
                </section>
            </section>
            <section class="chembond">
                <img src="assets/img/bonding.png" height="60" width="50" />
                <section class="chembond-content">
                    <p>This isn't much of a project, more homework. In Science we were asked to create a poster on the different types of bonding (ionic, metallic, covalent, etc) and I naturally said no as I cannot draw and hate making posters. I then did it as homework and made a website. It was a joint website with my friend <a href="ejayc.co.uk">Elliott</a> who did all the drawings/images, I then wrote the code. If you are wondering if my teacher like it then I can tell you that he did. If you want to see it then click <a href="projects/bonding/">here.</a> I know there is one mistake in the image but I have put a note at the bottom of that section.</p>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
```

So when I hover over the second icon I want the text in the box to be the same height as the first one is when you hover over it.

Comment: You could set the postion to relative and move it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should add to your css:

```
.chembond-content {
   display: none;
   float: right;
   width: 400px;
   position: relative;
   top: -72px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add margin-top with a negative value to your CSS, but NO.

A much more maintainable solution would be to have only one `<section class="content">` tag, align it, and with JS change the text when hovering over the relevant icon.

Comment: You're solution doesn't seem to work, just checked it in ff 24

Comment: You should edit you're answer, cause it is misleading for people who's first language isn't English.

Comment: I deleted the example to reduce confusion :-)

Answer (score 0):

when making a question here with simple CSS and HTML consider doing a jsFiddle and sharing that instead of a personal link, otherwise when this is working and your live link changes then the question will be irrelevant.

## The CSS Position Approach

So here is my fiddle minus a bit of code clutter:

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/3sTy9/)

The reason the second image is hovered to reveal the the `section` element with the class of `.chembond-content` and the element is not at the top (like the first image) is because you are floating it to the right but it's still part of the document flow after that image that you have right before the section.

If you want to have both elements open up in the same spot then you would get them out of the document flow by giving them a `fixed` or `absolute`  position which in this example I simple set it to 20 pixels from the top and from the right.

Since these elements are not taking up space in the flow of your markup then you are free to position both at the top if you want to.